# How to set the path of "Run application" in Metacity?

Tags: metacity

In Metacity, ALT-F2 opens a dialog "Run application". How to customize the $PATH that is used for autocompletion and running the command?

(It's not the $PATH of .bashrc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it is the $PATH of .profile because the .bashrc loads when you open a terminal but profile loads on login.